# Multiple parameter groups in Twirl templates

Tags: playframework, twirl

I'm just starting to learn about Twirl templating as part of the Play framework, and I was wondering if someone would be able to better explain the semantics of multiple parameter groups in a template.

I understand that one set of parameters (typically the first?) are ones that I am to supply myself.  I also noticed that any implicit parameters are listed last.

It's the second parameter group which in my tutorial's case says `(content: Html)`, where I'm not sure how it's used.

Right now I'm figuring that that Twirl goes through three stages of partially applying parameters: User, internal and implicit.  I could be way off on that though, someone set me straight!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a Twirl template compiles down to a Scala function. Scala functions can have multiple parameter groups, so Twirl templates can too. Really this is just syntactic sugar to make passing arguments more palatable with anonymous functions. For example:

```
scala> def foo(a:String, b: () => String) = { a + b() }
foo: (a: String, b: () => String)String

scala> foo("hello", { () => " there" } )
res2: String = hello there

scala> def foo(a:String)( b: () => String) = { a + b() }
foo: (a: String)(b: () => String)String

scala> foo("hello") { () => " there" }
res3: String = hello there
```

As you can see, the results are the same but the invocation syntax in the second case is "nicer".

Typically implicits are placed in the last group because then they don't need to be specified at all.

So, if you got a template `views.html.foo` which has a heading line like this:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
```

This is just making it easier for you to invoke it with something like:

```
Ok(views.html.foo("Title") { /* generate some html */ } )
```

You said:

> I'm figuring that that Twirl goes through three stages of partially applying parameters: User, internal and implicit. I could be way off on that though, someone set me straight!

Yes, you're way off on that. :) The arguments are evaluated in groups, but all before the invocation of the Twirl generated function occurs. Just think of it as syntactic sugar like above.